# Variable number of parameters in PHP

Tags: php

In the course of converting some code from Java to PHP, I came across the following Java code:

```
void doSomething(String requiered, String... optionals) {...}
```

I know it's possible to create a similar function signature using `func_get_args()` and I know I could also pass the unknown count of params in an array. However, neither seems straight forward to me, so I was wondering if there might be a better way to have a variable number of arguments in PHP.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list

Comment: @OfekRon - Not always, but instead of asking "How to convert this" you should perhaps have started out with your second edit (minus calling me a weirdo) and told us you where looking for alternatives? (Perhaps it would've been received better?).

Comment: @Epodax i thought that this is a too easy to answer question to overexplain myself, but i guess i was wrong...

Comment: @OfekRon Never assume something on other peoples behalf. Secondly, writing a good question not only benefits you with a proper / good answer but future people as well who might seek the same information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP 5.6 introduces ability to have this exact construct. 
From PHP manual:

> Argument lists may include the ... token to denote that the function accepts a variable number of arguments. The arguments will be passed into the given variable as an array

```
<?php
function sum($acc, ...$numbers) {
    foreach ($numbers as $n) {
        $acc += $n;
    }
    return $acc;
}

echo sum(1, 2, 3, 4);
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list

Comment: but i also need 1 arg to be requiered... can it be done also?

Comment: @OfekRon Yes, you can have a signature like `method(Type $required, Type $required, ...$optionals)`

Comment: @OfekRon however, be aware that this is a NEW construct introduced in 5.6. If you want your code to be compatible to older PHP versions, you must use func_get_args.